# Use a specific regular expression on all properties of string type in every model

Tags: c#, regex, model

I want to use a specific regular expression to validate every string property in my project. For example, to validate one property, I do this.

```
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[^\\/:*;\.\)\(]+$", ErrorMessage = "The characters ':', '.' ';', '*', '/' and '\' are not authorised")]
[Display(Name = "Name")]
public string Name{ get; set; }
```

How can I apply this to all properties with reflection ?

Answer (score 1):

Open find and replace box in Visual Studio, find all occurences  of `public string`, in replace paste:

```
[Required]\n[RegularExpression(@"^[^\\/:*;\.\)\(]+$", ErrorMessage = "The characters ':', '.' ';', '*', '/' and '\' are not authorised")]\n[Display(Name = "Name")]\npublic string
```

Also, check regular expressions, so it works with `\n` character correctly :)

And choose `Current Project` as scope for changes.

See the image:

[image]

Then just click "Replace all".

Comment: Ok, I'll do the find and replace on *.cs files in my Model's folder only. That's a workaround I haven't thought of ! ;)